# How can I create an URL to make a file downloadable automatically using HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, download

My problem:

I wanna be able to send to my costumers a link like `mywebsite.com/products` so they can download a `.xlsx` file and see what I'm seeling atm.

Is there any way to create a link like "`www.mywebsite.com/file`" so when the user access this URL the browser will open a prompt to download a `.xlsx` file?

Here's my `products.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://mywebsite.com/products.xlsx"/>
  </head>
</html>
```

I've already uploaded the `products.xlsx` to my server.

I've noted that if I access the website using the extension `.html`, it prompt's the user to download the file. If I access without the extension, it leads me to a 404 error.

Maybe it's my `.htaccess` config that is causing this?

Maybe the `Options +MultiViews` or the `HTML RewriteCond`..

```
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# ---- Make pages render without their extension in the url
Options +MultiViews


# Force HTTPS on the subdomains/subdirectories login or admin
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(login|admin)\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(login|admin)\. [NC,OR]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force WWW if no subdomain is given
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Remove html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, a simple anchor tag should do that

Comment: Hmm.. can you explain a little more? In my `index.html` file I'm using the following code in a button to prompt the user to download the file: `<p><a href="products.xlsx" download class="btn btn-common wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="2000ms">See Products</a></p>`. How can I set an anchor to this code and modify my `products.html` file in order to achieve the desired output? (An URL that "automatically" prompts the user to download the file)

Comment: The classes are confusing the issue on that element, as those are making Bootstrap treat that `<a>` differently. Just use a simple straight forward `<a href="something.xlsx">Click here</a>`

Comment: Ok, the `<a></a>` attribute isn't really my problem. The users can click my button and download the file. What I wanna achieve is to send a `marketable URL` to my clients, that when they access the URL, my code will prompt it to download the file... And by "marketable url" I mean that I don't wanna send them a link like "mywebsite.com/products.html". I wanna send something like "mywebsite.com/products".

Answer (score 1):

dot.Py do you want the link to the products.xlsx file to change depending on who it is you're speaking to? Ie. one client may have a particular products.xlsx file containing some information but another might have completely different information that they need to see.

If that's not the case, you can use an `<a>` tag to reference the link.

So for example:

```html
<a href='/excel/products.xlsx' target="_blank">Click to Download Excel Document</a>
```

Then all you'd need to do is include that within your `<body>` on the page and clients could click the link to download the file.

Comment: I don't need to change the file depending on the client. I need to make my client click the link "website.com/download" and then it prompts the user automatically to download the file.

Comment: Ah, well in that case just get your url to point to the file location within your folders.

For example if you keep the file next to index.html in a folder called excel, you'd remove the index.html from the url and replace that with /excel/products.xlsx.

This would automatically trigger a download.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP to serve a xlsx file upon loading the webpage :

```
<?php
$fileName = 'Products.xlsx';
$filePath = "[PATH]/products.xlsx";
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile($filePath);
```

Replace the [PATH] with your file path.

Comment: Be **very careful** using the `filesize(...)` value in the `Content-Length:` header; there are lots of reasons this can be incorrect and can cause the handler (Apache, nginx, etc.) to pass only part of the file as the whole file. I've found it's best simply to not use this header and let the browser sort it out itself.